# Calling a certain variable from a method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can write a method in such a way that I can later call a variable stored in it.

Of course, after I export and import into another Javascript file, I want to call the variable from the method, but I don't know exactly the syntax and if I have to use 'this'

I also don't know what to return to have all the declared variables available at any time

I want something like

```
class Security {
  chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance, BackEntrance) {
    FrontEntrance = //some code//
    BackEntrance = //some code//
  }
}

export default Security
```

And from another file, after import, call something like `Security.chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance)`

I hope I've set out all the data I need

Comment: Do you meant to access local variable defined in the method of a class from another class or function ?

Comment: You're probably thinking about this wrong. You may want a getter method to retrieve the value, or you may want to expand the scope of the variable to the class or window object (global). Be sure you're not asking an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Variables inside a function are local to the function and only exist when the function is executed.

Comment: Whatever you do, format your code properly in the future, for your benefit and ours.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. By typing `Security.chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance)` you ask to execute the function and not get the variable in the function. We need more context to answer you propely but an answer can be either to store the variable somewhere in the script wich call the function or to create a field in the class `Security` and retrieve it later with a getter like this:

```
class Security{
    frontEntrance

    getFrontEntrance(){
        return frontEntrance
    }

    chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance,BackEntrance){
      FrontEntrance=//some code//
      BackEntrance=//some code//
    }

  }
export default Security
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Something dubious happened to me and I would like to ask you why. In the sense that from everything you wrote to me in the code, I only managed to get the sequence class Security{ chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance,BackEntrance){
      FrontEntrance=//some code//
      BackEntrance=//some code//
    } } export default Security   and then import it in another file and call with security.chooseEntrance('FrontEntrance') and it works. Why without getter and without first declaration "frontEntrance" it's works?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Security {
  FrontEntrance;
  BackEntrance;
  chooseEntrance(FrontEntrance, BackEntrance) {
    this.FrontEntrance = FrontEntrance;
    this.BackEntrance = BackEntrance;
  }
}

export default Security;
```

from some other class you access

```js
const security = new Security();
security.chooseEntrance('', '');


security.FrontEntrance;
security.BackEntrance;
```